# How to use typeface in notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-fonts

Is it possible to use typeface in notification message, so that I can change the font? I have searched all over internet but couldnt get any solution or code.So that I cant tell you, what I have tried so far. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you...

Edit: I have found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView) that we can use custom layouts for notification.So, is it possible to access textview in custom layout, and use typeface?

Comment: This is not possible, and any hack might break anytime on different device/update.

Answer (score -5):

Notifications contain textViews and you can always setTypeface on textViews.

Comment: Thanks.Can you please explain, how to set typeface to notification textview? I know how to set it on a normal textview.