# How to set Custom Font?

Tags: android, notifications, android-typeface

Notification contain textViews, so we setTypeface on textView.
But I don't know how to achieve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215928/how-to-set-typeface-for-custom-notification-in-android

[How to use typeface in notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803571/how-to-use-typeface-in-notification)

[image: i need to create notification like this]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. There is no way to set the `Typeface` on a `RemoteViews`, let alone on a standard `Notification` layout.